# Split tubing assembly

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pumps, fluid, tubing

I am designing a tubing (TPE) assembly that splits a single inlet line into either four or eight outlet lines. The goal is to achieve an approximately equal flow rate of mildly viscous liquid at each of the outlets while placing a peristaltic pump on the single inlet line. Is this possible for low flow rates?

My initial thought was using a series of Y (Wye) reducers (i.e. inlet tubing is 1/2" ID and is split to two 3/8" tubes, which are split to four 1/4" tubes). However, I'm not sure if this setup would guarantee flow to each of the lines at low flow rates.

I also came across four way [rake tubing splitters](https://www.growgeneration.com/active-aqua-4-outlet-plastic-air-manifold.html?dfw_tracker=154258-AAPADIVP4&utm_campaign=Std-Shopping-Hydroponic-Sol8_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=654671777248&utm_term=&adgroupid=151706472687&gclid=Cj0KCQjw9fqnBhDSARIsAHlcQYTj-pbAJp4_PUrDDNRN6cJSpX7SeeyacC0bfEltl4cTrFHILeYzaYcaApSkEALw_wcB) but I'm not sure if these would work for my application.

Any advice or feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Look into manifold design.  If you make the conditions at every leg of the manifold the same, you may get close to what you want, but there are other ways too.  If you use a peristaltic pump, you can have one motor drive several tubes.